# Chrome Extension and Jenkins URL's

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, jenkins, continuous-integration, content-security-policy

I'm currently trying to develop a chrome extension which is supposed to display data from different Jenkins servers. The url to the jenkins server is being entered by the user.

So basically what I need is being able to access any kind of jenkins url.

My problem is that Chrome's [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy)
only allows you to access domains which you've registered in the manifest.json like so:

`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://localhost:8080/; object-src 'self'"`.

But since different users are going to enter different urls, I'd need to be able to change this policy dynamically, and I don't really know how to do that.

Comment: very nice idea.. i am also awaiting for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem have a misconception as to what is needed to send a request to a random domain.

CSP directive `script-src` dictates where you can *execute code from* specifically by `<script src="https://some.domain/script.js">`. That, indeed, is something you can't whitelist.

To send GET/POST cross-site requests, you need a [host permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#requesting-permission), not a CSP modification.

There are 2 possible approaches:

- Give yourself wide permissions, e.g. `"*://*/*"` or `"<all_urls>"`. This will allow you to query anything at the cost of install-time warning *"can read and modify data on all websites"*.
- Use the [optional permissions API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions). That way, you can avoid the install-time warning and prompt for elevated permissions as the extension is configured. This would make sense if this configuration needs to be done infrequently.

  Extra note: as of 2016-10-04, `permissions` API is not implemented in Firefox WebExtensions / Edge Extensions, so if portability is a concern, it's best avoided for new projects for now.

Comment: Thanks for answering my almost 2 year old question :D

But yes, you're right. I ended up going with the first solution you posted. Giving the all_urls permission.

Having that warning wasn't really a problem for this project, since it was only for a small contest held by my school.

Comment: Welcome! It was edited relatively recently and the existing answer isn't good.

Comment: Oh yeah, I think I looked at this a couple days ago by accident and found a spelling error. Couldn't let that go :p

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to dynamically change the manifest once the extension has been installed. Per Google https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-remote-script :

> Generic wildcards such as https:, https://* and https://*.com are not allowed; subdomain wildcards such as https://*.example.com are allowed.

If you could ensure that the CI machines are all on same domain then it could work.

Comment: If you aren't able to register domains dynamically after installation, then there must be some other way to get JSON data from a nonspecific domain: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo This extension allows you to enter any JSON url and displays the data without any problems.

Comment: @guyyst I looked into the code of the rest client extension and they appear to be using [`<all_urls>`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) permission.